# How do I program an Arduino to ignore subsequent presses of a push button for 5 minutes after said button is pressed?

Tags: arduino

I am using a push button to trigger a relay; the code for that is below.

I want to program my Arduino to ignore any subsequent presses of the push button for a period of 5 minutes. How do I include this function in my Arduino sketch?

The purpose of this is to disable the user from being able to repeatedly trigger the relay by repeatedly pressing the push button until a 5 minute interval has passed. This is for a public art piece and, as follows, such limitations need to be imposed to guarantee appropriate usage of the piece.

```
int pinButton = 8;
int Relay = 2;
int stateRelay = LOW;
int stateButton;
int previous = LOW;
long time = 0;
long debounce = 500;
int stayON = 5000; //stay on for 5000 ms

void setup() {
  pinMode(pinButton, INPUT);
  pinMode(Relay, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  stateButton = digitalRead(pinButton);  
  if(stateButton == HIGH && previous == LOW && millis() - time > debounce) {
    if(stateRelay == HIGH){
      digitalWrite(Relay, LOW);
    } else {
       digitalWrite(Relay, HIGH);
       delay(stayON);
       digitalWrite(Relay, LOW);
    }
    time = millis();
  }
  previous == stateButton;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a variable to store the last time that the display was activated. You could then change your else statement to an elseif statement in which you compare the current run time against the last time it was activated. This would work similar to the debounce method that you used.

```
long lastActivated = 0; //last time display was activated
long myDelay = 300000; //5 minutes in millis


  if(stateButton == HIGH && previous == LOW && millis() - time > debounce) {
    if(stateRelay == HIGH){
      digitalWrite(Relay, LOW);
    } else if (millis() - lastActivated > myDelay) { //verifies it's been 5 minutes
       digitalWrite(Relay, HIGH);
       delay(stayON);
       digitalWrite(Relay, LOW);
       lastActivated = millis(); //resets lastActivated when display is allowed to activate
    }
    time = millis();
  }
```

Comment: Note that `millis()` [overflows after about 50 days](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Millis), and so a button press 50 days and between 0 and 5 minutes after the previous one will also be ignored. This is an unlikely edge case though as Arduinos typically don't run for 50 straight.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the behavior of the device that the relay is operating.  If the relay should be ***ON*** for the entire time the art piece is operating, then use a simple `delay()`:

```
int waitFiveMinutes = 300000;
// ... other stuff ...

void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(pinButton) == LOW)
  {
    digitalWrite(Relay, HIGH);
    delay(waitFiveMinutes);
    digitalWrite(Relay, LOW);
  }
}
```

If you only need to trigger the relay once, like for a garage door opener, then you delay on the button press:

```
void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(pinButton) == LOW)
  {
    triggerRelay();
    delay(waitFiveMinutes);
  }
}

void triggerRelay() {
  digitalWrite(Relay, HIGH);
  delay(200);  // you might not need this
  digitalWrite(Relay, LOW);
}
```

Either way, the button should not respond during the delay.  If it *is* responding, you may be accidentally bypassing the relay on your breadboard.